# Printing Labels in Java swing application

Tags: java, swing

I have to develop an java swing application that will take customer details (name, address, contact number) and print each set on information to sticky labels. There are 10 labels per A4 sheet in a 5 x 2 matrix (each cell size 96 x 50.8 mm).

Does anyone know if there are other java API's out there designed specificly for printing?

Comment: [`java.awt.print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/package-summary.html) Provides classes and interfaces for a general printing API.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Some people ... just don't know that Google exists! :D

Answer (score 3):

Like said, `java.awt.print` is the package to look up. There are official tutorials avialable here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/